# How to write hover using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if hover on the button tag, it 'll show the social buttons with spaces.
When I mouse over in the space between two social icons, the follo.w button flickers for a moment We should not show follow button if I move even in between icons.

```
<div class="visible-lg visible-md">
    <button class="btn follow-btn text-center" onmouseover="$(this).hide().next().show();">Follow Benedict on social media</button>

    <div class="social-btn text-center" onmouseout="$(this).hide().prev().show();">
        <a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/BenedictEvans" target="_blank">
            <img src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/twitter.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </a>
        <a class="btn" href="http://ben-evans.com/" target="_blank">
            <img src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/blog.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </a>
        <a class="btn" href="https://soundcloud.com/a16z" target="_blank">
            <img src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/soundcloud.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </a>
        <a class="btn" href="http://www.slideshare.net/bge20" target="_blank">
            <img src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/slideshare.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </a>
        <a class="btn" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/benedictevans" target="_blank">
            <img src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/linkedin.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added the fiddle here:
    http://jsfiddle.net/thangadurai1992/g9rasopd/

Comment: Can you complete the adress for your images in your example? At the moment they are referring to your local computer.

Comment: You should use `onmouseleave` which bubbles unlike `onmouseout`. But using inline script as you do makes your code 'kind of' unreadable...  http://jsfiddle.net/g9rasopd/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could always use css for this. It works by using a wrapper div and having the hover effect on the parent.

```css
img {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px;
}
button {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.wrapper:hover button {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Follow Text Here</button>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
</div>
```

Note: The margin used on the button and image tags are for demo only, and can be removed without breaking the functionality.

I have placed the css (to keep it clean) directly onto the img and button tags. In order for you to ensure it only applies to this button / these images, you could select them via class:

```css
.social {
  height: 30px;
  margin:5px;
}
.follow {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:5px;
  position: absolute;
}
.wrapper:hover .follow {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="follow">Follow Benedict on social media</button>
  <img class="social" src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/twitter.png" />
  <img class="social"  src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/blog.png" />
  <img class="social"  src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/soundcloud.png" />
  <img class="social"  src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/slideshare.png" />
  <img class="social"  src="/assets/new_home/influential-images/Icons/linkedin.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS on this one.

I just added a container and set an hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/g9rasopd/6/

```
.social-btn-container:hover .follow-btn{
    display: none;
}

.social-btn-container:hover .social-btn{
    display: inline-block;
}
```